# Pass kendo batch items to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

I'm trying to implement batch editing into my current project using a kendo grid and datasource. I've never done batch editing before so I've run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I can get my grid to pass all of the changes to the action on my controller but the model on the action is `null`.

Here is what my action looks like:

```
public JsonResult CreateQuestionItem(IEnumerable<ItemTemplateViewModel> model) 
{
    // process data and return result
}
```

When I look at Fiddler I can see that the datasource is passing the data to the controller somewhat like this:

```
models[0][Id]: 0
models[0][Name]: Test 1
models[1][Id]: 0
models[1][Name]: Test 2
```

Is there anyway I can convert the way it passes in the data so it matches exactly to my model? Or what should my model look like in order to match the data being passed in?

This is what my model currently looks like:

```
public class ItemTemplateViewModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So the data is being passed from view to controller, but the model object isn't being filled up? Maybe add in a screenshot from Fiddler, and the code for your grid.

Comment: Please share the code for your view/grid so we can see how you're passing data from the view to your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo sends the model with the name models, and your variable is called model. I can't recall whether changing the variable to be models

```
IEnumerable<ItemTemplateViewModel> models
```

would work, but I know I've used a bind prefix before for this:

```
public JsonResult CreateQuestionItem([Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ItemTemplateViewModel> model) 
{
    // process data and return result
}
```